# Maven 3.3.9 version - "SSLCertificate not matching" Error through Maven cmd not But working fine with in eclipse

Tags: maven, maven-3

I have been automating server things using maven,surefire,testng,rest assured, java and eclipse.

I observed a weird issue that, my server test which hits a https website(eg) login https API) is working perfectly when I run the test script through the eclipse (eg)

```
 RunAs>> TestNG)
```

But when I am running the same test script through the maven command..cmd (eg)

```
mvn test -P Test..
```

I am unable to hit that hhtps webiste, and cmd throws me below error

```
"javax.net.ssl.SSlException: Certificate for <my https link> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names : [www.bingocrazy.com, bingocrazy.com]
```

Note: my https link is sometghing like this - abc.xyz.com

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please post some of your code so we can best help you here.

Comment: Runnig a maven java project with rest assured dependency to test the server for the https application.I observe that the project perfectly runs the rest assured code and gives the reponse when running the project as testNG from the eclipse manually. But on running the same project from the command prompt as "mvn test -PTest" , where Test is the same testNG file gives the 403 forbidden error for the same https application link.

Comment: Weird is here that, how the clipse is able to run the project but why not through maven command.

 I feel it is something with the maven server that needs to bypass before I call the https, some SSL certificate matching needs to be ignored. But I don't know how we do that.

I am using Maven 3.3.9 and following is the pom.xml that contains all the dependencies :